# MySQL table value1 less than table value2

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue here.
This is what I have: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE location='$locid' AND currentservers < maxservers");`

So, what I want to do is to select everything from a table where location is equal to the value and currentservers less than maxservers. I haven't tested this out yet since the whole function I'm making is quite large. currentservers and maxservers are columns in the table.

Will this query work?
Also, I only want to return 1 row. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Tom.

Comment: Why are you asking? Can't you wait to test it yourself? BTW don't use `mysql_query`. Use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: juergen d, I have been searching around and most people had huge queries that I didn't understand at all. My function is far from done and can't test it until it's completely done.

Comment: You can test that, just run the query and see what it says.

Comment: What if the query has more than 1 match? How do you determine which 1 you'd like to see?

Answer (score 1):

If both of your fields `currentservers` and `maxservers` are numerical you should get what you want appending " LIMIT 1" to the query:

```
"SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE location='$locid' AND currentservers < maxservers LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: Thank you Bruno! You're a life saver! I'll test this as soon as my function is done